# Not able to parse different parameters from a sentence using perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have following two strings

```
02/22/2017 10:15:19.312 AM: Information : Response Code : 98
02/22/2017 10:15:19.312 AM: Information : Response Code : 99 : TransactionID : 132
```

I need to extract following parameters -

1. Timestamp
2. Response Code
3. TransactionID (If present in the string)

I am using following pattern search

```
/^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})(.*\bResponse Code\b)(.*\b : \b)(\d+)(.*\bTransactionID\b)?(.*\b : \b)?(\d+)?/
```

Not able to extract TransactionID. Can you please let me know what is the wrong inthe regex ?

Comment: the code is giving pattern error in regex101

Comment: pls post correct cod

Comment: It is being used in NXLOG tool. NXLog tool uses perl scripting feature to extract strings.

Comment: if $raw_event !~ /^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})(.*\bResponse Code\b)(.*\b : \b)(\d+)(\s)?(*.\d+)?/ drop();
  $timewithdate = parsedate(string(strptime($1,"%m/%d/%Y")));
  $Responsecode = integer($4);
  $TransactionId = integer($6);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using greedy `.*` in your regex it matching up to last `:`.

You need to make it non-greedy and remove unwanted groups:

```
/^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}).*\bResponse Code\b.*?\b : \b\d+(?:.*\bTransactionID\b.* : \b)?(\d+)?/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DURofv/2)

Comment: Thanks Anubhava! I tried the the given regex. Added some parentheses to get responsecode ... /^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})(.*\bResponse Code\b.*?\b : \b)(\d+)(?:.*\TransactionID\b.* : \b)?(\d+)?/      It is still giving transaction id as null

Comment: [You can see here it is working fine and matching both response code and transaction id](https://regex101.com/r/DURofv/3)

Comment: I think it is due to 'gm' option it is working in perl editor... Can you please let me know how to put that option in my case.

Comment: In `perl` you can use: `m/^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}).*\bResponse Code\b.*?\b : \b\d+(?:.*\bTransactionID\b.* : \b)?(\d+)?/mg`

Comment: ^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})(.*\bResponse Code : \b)(\d+)(.* TransactionID.* : )?(\d+)? worked for me in NXLOG. \b was causing issue to parse TransactionID. Thanks Anubhava for giving your valuable time :)